# Mysql query rand() and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-order-by

Hi i'm trying to get some random results ordered by the location ASC.

This is my query:

```
SELECT `location`, `route`
FROM (`foo`)
WHERE `location` != ''
ORDER BY  RAND(), `location` ASC
LIMIT 8
```

the problem is that it gets randomly but doesn't orders then by "location" ASC, also if i do this:

```
SELECT `location`, `route`
FROM (`foo`)
WHERE `location` != ''
ORDER BY  `location` ASC,RAND()
LIMIT 8
```

it doesn't gets randomly.

How can i get both togheter `RAND()` and `ORDER BY location ASC`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need nested statements/queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT `location`, `route`
    FROM `foo`
    WHERE `location` != ''
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 8) AS `temp`
ORDER BY `location` ASC;
```

Comment: i need 4 minutes to accept the answer, anyway this solves at all! really thanks!

Comment: Note that this method will be very, very slow if your table is very large - it will require full table scan, even with LIMIT 8